# How to fix unison failing with "Fatal error: Internal error: New archives are not identical" for identical paths?

Tags: ssh, unison

When trying to sync two paths (one of which is remote) via `ssh`, unison fails with

> Fatal error: Internal error: New archives are not identical.

while syncing via a network mount works just fine.

While `unison -debug all` yields no indication on the possible error, having it use `ssh -v` causes a lot of

> channel 0: bad ext data

errors. However, both machines run the same version of unison (2.40.63).

Comment: It looks like this problem is also affecting Fedora 18, which now includes OCaml 4.00.1. It looks like packaging three versions of Unison wasn't enough to make the program usable. :(

Comment: @amcnabb Good catch, did you post a bug report? The [Karl M Windows version](http://alan.petitepomme.net/unison/index.html) is probably still widely in use, apart from the interoperability issues with any older distribution. The hash inconsistencies are of course a bug in unison/OCaml themselves as well...

Comment: It's also an issue with Arch Linux, although _there_ there's a [2.32 PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=46811), and the [Downgrading Arch-Wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_Packages) may be helpful as well

Comment: @amcnabb At least my locally compiled unison binary is a standalone one with static linking, so you can probably just use e.g. the 2.32/Ocaml3.12 build from another distro on the same architecture. Some x86 and and x86_64 builds are available [on the unison homepage](http://alan.petitepomme.net/unison/index.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As hinted at by [this macports.org ticket](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/35407), the problem lies in having used two different major versions of OCaml (3.12 vs 4.0) in compilation on the two machines. Either use the *same* binary on both machines or (as was the case for me due to different architectures) recompile unison with *identical* OCaml versions.

(Side note: The [Windows version compiled by Karl M](http://alan.petitepomme.net/unison/index.html) requires OCaml 3.12)

Comment: Thanks for a very succinct and useful answer.  This is made worse by the fact that the Unison build on Debian squeeze currently fails, so I had to use a binary built with the wrong OCaml version.